# Html Helpers generates ID from model properties. How do I target 1 particular element with JavaScript and CSS if many elements have the same ID?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

As it's recommended, Javascript must be kept in a physically separate file (to be unobtrusive). So how do I access a particular element in particular page? should I detect those elements by id? that would mean 2 elements can't have the same id even if they are not located in the same page.

Well, for instance, using the Html helpers methods generates element's name + id from the model's properties. If I use the same model in several pages, many elements will have the same id. How can I target them in different pages. By the way, CSS work the same way.

**EDIT**

Let's say I've this

```
<% = Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)%>
```

It will generates

```
<input type = "Text" name = "FirstName" id = "FirstName"/>
```

Let's say I've this textbox in 2 differen pages. If want, for instance, to disable the textbox located in page A, how do I do it knowing they are two of them in 2 different pages. **How do I discriminate them from my external javascript file?**

Thanks for helping

Comment: To clarify, same model (eg Product) used on several pages (eg Edit, Update pages). If this is the case, there is no concern. If you are referring to the same model used in several Partials Views on the same page, then your question to me makes a bit more sense.

Comment: I think you will be answering your question :) -  How do you discriminate them currently?

Comment: @Ahmad: read my post. till now, I give my elements different id so that, I can target them from a external file. But, with MVC, elements are generated using using Html Helper methods, which uses property's name to generate both id and name of element. So you gets the same ids in several pages if you use the same model

Comment: I assume you 'give my elements different id' using the HtmlHelper overloads eg. `<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { id = "UniqueIDForFirstNameOnPageA" })%>`

Comment: @Ahmad: I didn't know that I could do that. interesting then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that for each page the uses the same model, you create a wrapper `div`

```
<div class="pageA">
   // the model stuff here
   <% = Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)%> 
</div>

<div class="pageB">
   // the model stuff here
   <% = Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)%>
</div>
```

and then use Jquery selectors to get the correct element `$(".pageA input[name='FirstName']")` (not sure if this syntax is correct).

Answer (score 1):

Well JavaScript may be kept in a separate file or not, but it is definitely included as part of the HTML send to the browser for a particular page. I Hope I've understood your question, but, generally if you have you JavaScript code in a file, lets say `utils.js` then in your html generated should include (probably within the `<head>` tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/utils.js"></script>
```

The script get included in the page, and when the browser encounters this, it loads and then runs the script, for **that** page. Therefore, it is not important what the ids for elements on different pages are.
Does that make sense, or have I completely misunderstood your question?

**Update:**

Ok, so based on your comments, I think I understand. You have

```
//Page 1
//When loaded, this input should flash blue via javascript for example
<input id="firstName" .../>
```

And

```
//Page 2
//When loaded, this input has some other fancy effect/behaviour
<input id="firstName" .../>
```

Well in this case, as far as I see, there are only 2 types of answers. Have two seperate external js files, one per page and this way you can change to your hearts content ...**OR**... have some sort of hidden field in your page that tells your script what page it is looking at (this seems hacky)

```
<input type="hidden" value="page1"/> //etc..
```

Comment: drinker: I'm sorry. I'm the one who didn't ask well the question. Look at the Edit above.

Comment: drinker: I see what you mean. The browser doesn't care what id's are in the page. It just loads the javascript. I believe I should have asked the question differently. So look at the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements on the page with the same `id`. [That isn't valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

So when you use the same HTML helper multiple times, you need to pass different names:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("Foo", Model.Foo) %>
<%: Html.TextBox("Bar", Model.Bar) %>
```

Comment: @Hello Craig. good to have you again. It's not valid to have the same id twice in the same page. But, do you agree that I can have the same id in 2 different pages? In that case, How do I target one of them from my external javascript file?

Comment: OK, I didn't understand your original question. I think more info is needed here. Why are you disabling this in JavaScript? Your motivation might suggest a solution.

Comment: Also: What is stopping you from passing different names in the different pages, as with my code example?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but are you saying, you have some elements with the same id, on multiple pages, that you want to attach different behaviour to?  If so then this could help you out.   if not,  then what Craig said.

You can use more specific selectors, or give your selectors context 
have a look at the documentations here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/
under this header:
jQuery( selector, [ context ] )
it explains a bit about selects and context.     you should be able to use this and some creative page building to target the right element with your jQuery.

Comment: You are right. This is what I meant. I've same ids in different pages because they are generated by the helper methods. I'd like to attach different behaviors.

Comment: He didn't say he's using jQuery.

Comment: very true jason!  a poor assumption on my part.

Comment: Thanks very much, although I needed to put extra thoughts to understand what was [context] in your answer (Ah!).

Answer (score 1):

So you have two files, each with a text field with the id "FirstName". When you're script runs on Page A you want to disable the field, but not when your script runs on Page B.

Is the structure of the two pages identical? I suspect not if you're handling these fields differently. Use the context to your advantage. Like if the one on Page A is in a div with id "thisDiv" and the other is in a div with id "thatDiv" you could `document.getElementById('thisDiv')`. If you get an element then disable the field, if not do nothing.

If you want a more specific answer you're going to have to give us more context.